# How to make big classes more elegant?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, design-patterns

In my Objective-C app some view controllers have dozens of IBOutlets and 40+ methods. It's getting really hard to read through the code. I tried to limit the number of properties and methods by declaring them in separate controller classes.

Is there some good practice to limit the amount of code in a class or do I have to just accept it as my class has many tasks to control ?

Comment: Are you following MVC pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have pretty much ended up with something called Massive View Controllers.

Please look on to the below link.

https://talk.objc.io/collections/refactoring-large-view-controllers

There are more ways to mitigate the problem. If I am right you might be following MVC. If so you should consider following MVP / MVVM / VIPER architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in iOS app programming, a view controller gets big because it does the tasks which should belong to other layers. These layers are:

1. The C in MVC: *view* controllers are actually not the C in MVC. The C in MVC does not directly keep references to the view objects (Label, Button etc.). Rather, it exposes methods receiving requests sent from the view objects or from anywhere including view controllers. The code of C does not mention UI classes. Its task is converting the “raw” requests to something the inner layer understands, and passing to the inner layer, which is
2. The business logic layer (the M in MVC): code in this layer definitely must not know anything about UI.

Take a simple example: if you business logic is about calculating the sum of two integer numbers, and your UI has two textboxes, then the C would have the task of converting two strings to two integer numbers. In this example, the view controller is merely a manager which holds references to the two textboxes. It knows how to directly manipulate these textboxes, how to receive events from these textboxes, and how to call the (real) controller.

In conclusion, to fix your problem, just extract some code in your view controller to the layers above.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in MVC, the 'C'ontroller has so much to do like handling the lifecycle events of a view, handling the view callbacks in IBActions and several other tasks like that. If we are doing something with the data from the 'M'odel that is also done in Controller. For Ex. Transform Date object to String and show in 'V'iew or show some count after processing.

The code which is not responsible for the managing the views and plays with the data can be moved to other classes. This whole new design pattern is called MVVM - Model-View-ViewModel. The ViewModels will have the data manipulation related methods. I guess this would help Viewcontrollers to get some relief from handling so many things and shrink a little codewise.

If you want to get some more insights for MVVM design pattern, Go through the below link :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/34-design-patterns-by-tutorials-mvvm

Hope this would be helpful to you.